# django select related with 3 tables

Tags: python, django

i have 3 models in django like this:

```
class SlackConfigurationMode(models.Model):
MODES = (
    ("NORMAL", "normal"),
    ("ALERT", "alert"),
    ("DANGER", "danger")
)

mode = models.CharField(choices=MODES, default=MODES[0][0], max_length=20)
time_send_slack_notification_minute = models.IntegerField(default=0)
time_send_slack_notification_hour = models.IntegerField(default=0)
description = models.TextField(blank=True)

class WebHookConfiguration(models.Model):
    webhook_url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slack_configuration_mode = models.ForeignKey(
        SlackConfigurationMode,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='webhook_configurations'
    )

class MonitorSource(models.Model):
    TYPES = (
        ("FACEBOOK", "facebook"),
        ("WEBSITE", "website"),
        ("YOUTUBE", "youtube")
    )

    target = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField(choices=TYPES, max_length=20)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey("auth.User", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slack_configuration = models.ForeignKey(
        SlackConfigurationMode, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,
        default=SlackConfigurationMode.objects.filter(mode="NORMAL")[0].id,
        related_name='monitor_sources'
    )
```

i want to get data of webhook_configuration and monitorsource filter by slackconfiguration by mode
i use this query:

```
queryset = SlackConfigurationMode.objects.select_related('webhook_configurations', 'monitor_sources').filter(
    mode='HIGH'
)
```

but have the error:
Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'monitor_sources', 'webhook_configurations'. Choices are: (none)

how can i fix it, and why my query won't work, tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, `webhook_configurations` and `monitor_sources` are ***reverese relations*** and hence you must use [**`prefetch_related(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related)

```
queryset = SlackConfigurationMode.objects \
    .prefetch_related('webhook_configurations', 'monitor_sources') \
    .filter(mode='HIGH')
```

Comment: it works, tks u so much, but can i ask 1 more , how can i get that data from webhook_configurations and monitor_sources by this queryset ?